# How to have a background which exactly fits the text height/depth?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions, bounding-box

I tried with a background starting from `text` anchor or from `base` anchor, and with a `colorbox` without sep, but the top of the "S" and the bottom of the "p" are a little bit above of the background borders.

Is it possible to set them exactly without manually adjusting? Did I do something wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}                   
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}       
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\mydepth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\begin{document}                      
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\Huge Stop}
\settodepth{\mydepth}{\Huge Stop}
\settoheight{\myheight}{\Huge Stop}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                       
    \node[draw=gray, very thick, font=\Huge] (stop) {Stop};
    \scoped[on background layer] 
        \draw[lightgray,fill=lightgray] (stop.text) -- 
             ++(0,\myheight) -- ++(\mywidth, 0) --
             ++(0,-\myheight) -- ++(0,-\mydepth)  -- 
             ++(-\mywidth, 0) -- cycle;
    \node[draw=gray, very thick, font=\Huge, below=1ex of stop] 
        (another) {Stop};
    \scoped[on background layer] 
        \draw[lightgray,fill=lightgray] (another.base) --
            ++(-.5\mywidth,0) --     
            ++(0,\myheight) -- ++(\mywidth, 0) --
            ++(0,-\myheight) -- ++(0,-\mydepth)  -- 
            ++(-\mywidth, 0) -- ++(0,\mydepth);
    \node[draw=gray, very thick, font=\Huge, below=1ex of another]
        (andanother) {\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{lightgray}{Stop}};
\end{tikzpicture}                                         
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TeX can't know the exact content of each glyph. TeX knows only the bounding boxes provided by the font (via the `.tfm` file).

Comment: tex has no information about the character shapes other than the height and depth as specified in the font metrics, if the font designer chooses to make the character stray out of that area than there is no way to tell. You can of course always make fboxsep a bit bigger than 0pt, for luck.

Comment: the important thing to note that it **is not the fault** of the person who implemented `\colorbox`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! Of course it is not, there is the same problem also without `\colorbox` :):):)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you! Since you were the first to comment, if you would like to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX has no information about the exact content of each glyph. TeX knows only the bounding boxes provided by the font (via the `.tfm` file).

As  [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) says in his comment, *if the font designer chooses to make the character stray out of that area than there is no way to tell*.

Answer (score 23):

TeX does know the glyph bounding boxes as they are reported by the font. Usually, these bounding boxes are not exact:

- Side bearings are added (left and right space).
- Curvy elements tend to stick a little outside.
- Sometimes the glyph is outside the bounding box by design, example: `\not`.

The example of the question uses font `cmr17.pfb`. A font editor like `fontforge` reveals the real dimensions of the glyphs:

- Left side bearing of `S`: 46
- Height of `S`: 699
- Depth of `p`: -195
- Right side bearing of `p`: 33

The font uses 1000 units for 1 em. However, `1em` by TeX is a little smaller. The right value is the nominal value `24.88pt` of the font: `OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88` (result of `\the\font`).

Combined:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newsavebox\StopBox
\sbox\StopBox{%
  \Huge
  \wlog{Font: \the\font}% Font: \OT1/cmr/m/n/24.88
  \dimen0=24.88pt
  \kern-.046\dimen0\relax % cancel left side bearing of S/cmr17
  \smash{Stop}% no height, no depth
  \kern-.033\dimen0\relax % cancel right side bearing of p/cmr17
  \vrule
    width 0pt
    height .699\dimen0 % height of S
    depth .195\dimen0 % depth of p
  \relax
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw=gray, very thick, font=\Huge] (stop) {%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox\StopBox}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Very interesting! Is there a way to automatically get the left and right spaces around a letter?

Comment: @Jander [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/) can be scripted with Python: [Writing python scripts to change fonts in FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/python.html). Maybe this helps to develop a more automatic procedure.